# Topological Boundary of $\{f < c\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

if $f \in C^1(\Omega,\mathbb{R})$, with $\Omega$ open and bounded, $c \in \mathbb{R}$, what is the topological boundary of:
$$\{ x \in \Omega: f(x)<c\}$$
Is always $f^{-1}(c)=\{ x \in \Omega: f(x)=c\}$?

Really thanks.

Comment: What if $f \equiv c$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boundary of $\{c: f(x) <c\}$ is $\{c: f(x) =c\}$ iff $c$ is not the  local minimum value of $f$ at any point of $\Omega$.

Comment: Thanks. Another question: what can I say about the topological boundary if $c$ is a local minimum?

Comment: @Papemax89 In general you can only say that the boundary is not equal to $f^{-1}(c)$. It is not possible to describe the boundary.

Comment: Really thanks @Kabo Murphy for your answer. Last question: if I consider $A=\{ x \in \Omega: f(x) < c, \nabla f (x) \neq 0\}$, in this case, case holds true $\partial A=f^{-1}(c)$?

Comment: @Papemax89 Still not true. But if you assume that  the gradient is $\neq 0$ for all $x \in $\Omega$ then it is true.

Answer (score 1):

No. Example: let $ \Omega = (0,1)$ and $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in \Omega.$ Then $\{ x \in \Omega: f(x)<1\} = \Omega$, but $\{ x \in \Omega: f(x)=1\} = \emptyset.$

Comment: Thanks. What I can say about $\partial \{ x \in \Omega: f(x)<c\}$? Are there conditions to impose on $f$ to conclude that $\partial\{ x \in \Omega: f(x)<c\}=f^{-1}(c)$?